# SimpleDateFormat produces different timezone outputs in Android vs JDK

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

There's a lot of questions on here on SimpleDateFormat but I can't seem to find anything on this issue. I'm running into issues with different output from the exact same code running on Android vs the JDK. I'm running in Eclipse and using the emulator to test Android. JDK version 1.7 and Android 4.4.

Any ideas on how to make Android output dates in the JDK style format?

```
TimeZone GMT_ZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
String RFC1123_PATTERN = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";

final DateFormat rfc1123Format = new SimpleDateFormat(RFC1123_PATTERN, LOCALE_US);
rfc1123Format.setTimeZone(GMT_ZONE);
String dateString = rfc1123Format.format(new Date());
```

JDK 1.7 dateString value: Fri, 20 Dec 2013 00:46:21 **GMT**

Android 4.4 dateString value: Fri, 20 Dec 2013 00:46:21 **GMT+00:00**

Comment: Android is a re-implementation with some differences, maybe try a different pattern? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584647/simpledateformat-parse-is-one-hour-out-using-rfc-1123-gmt-in-summer

Comment: I'm sorry to read you're using the emulator. Holy cow it's slow. You'll have to just rely on what Android uses or drop the 'z' from the pattern

Comment: Yeah, I do realize Android and JDK are different (hence why I have to do so much work getting them to play nice). However, I really do need the JDK-style pattern as I'm working with another service which requires that format. Any idea what pattern would produce the Fri, 20 Dec 2013 00:46:21 GMT format output on Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Android != Java

Android libraries are an imitation of the Java libraries but not exact copies. Thus [the lawsuit between Oracle and Google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_v._Google). So you may see variations in behavior.

### Joda-Time

If you want a consistent, and superior, experience when doing work with date-times, use the third-party open-source [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Joda-Time is meant to supplant the notoriously bad java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

### JSR 310

Another option might be the Java 7 backport of [JSR 310: Date and Time API](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) java.time.* classes bundled with Java 8.

### RFC 1123 Format

Regarding the follow-up question you added as a comment:

> Any idea what pattern would produce the Fri, 20 Dec 2013 00:46:21 GMT format output on Android?

Surprisingly, Joda-Time 2.3 seems to lack a built-in formatter for that old [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) format. But the following home-brew format seems to do the job, provided you remember to convert the DateTime to UTC, as shown below.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime nowInParis = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'").withLocale( Locale.US );
String nowInParisAsStringGMT = formatter.print( nowInParis.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "nowInParisAsStringGMT: " + nowInParisAsStringGMT );
System.out.println( "nowInParis: " + nowInParis );
```

When run…

```
nowInParisAsStringGMT: Fri, 20 Dec 2013 05:03:58 GMT
nowInParis: 2013-12-20T05:03:58.175+01:00
```

Comment: Thanks! I did realize they were different, but considering both have examples in which the "z" should produce the GMT (not the GMT+) style output I wondered if this was a known bug or if I misunderstood the documentation. Perhaps some additional setting I needed?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your settings question. But I do know this is just the first of many headaches waiting for you if you continue to use java.util.Date/Calendar classes or their imitations in Android. There is no reason to not use Joda-Time (or backport of JSR 310) but one: Some folks report a slowdown on first call to Joda-Time in Andoid (Android only, no problem at all on a real Java platform). I don't know the details of the slowdown problem. But with the caveat that you investigate that problem, I strongly recommend switching to Joda-Time or JSR 310 and never look back.

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to use JodaTime, but the detailed description of how to use it (and the Android caveat) is helpful. I'll mark you as the answer for now unless someone else can answer the more complex formatting follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of Basil's answer for those who don't want to use Joda-Time:

```
private String toRfc1123(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", Locale.US);
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```